# PHP выполнение единого скрипта, прерывание работы остальных

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, есть немного странная задача, сейчас постараюсь объяснить.

Есть скрипт, который выполняется несколько минут, с интервалами sleep. Вызывается он простым запросом, когда пользователь находится на сайте.

Назначение этого скрипта, определенные действия в бд, то есть выборка, затем обновление.

Но дело в том, что результат выполнения этого скрипта является общим для всех, по этому будет немного глупо, если одновременно  20 пользователей запустят 5ти минутный  скрипт, после чего к примеру первый вернет результат, который повлияет на данные всех остальных пользователей, а не только юзера вызвавшего его, а остальные 4 будут ещё несколько минут просто так работать.

Возможно ли как то сделать, если второй юзер отправил этот запрос, прервать работу прошлого вызванного скрипта и запрашивать новый результат, или же прервать текущий и ждать ответа старого?

Грубо говоря, имеем скрипт который находится в sleep(), и когда мы вызываем новый, нужно отключить работу того же старого.

P.S. Cron для этих задач не подойдет, так как скрипт не сильно используемый, и может быть вообще не вызван в течении нескольки часов.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант:

1. при старте скрипта сгенерируй какую-нибудь рандомную строку;
2. создай файл (если его нет) some_script_started.txt и запиши туда эту строчку;
3. после каждого sleep() проверяй, совпадает ли твоя рандомная строка, что хранится в переменной со строчкой из файла.

3.1. если да - продолжай работу скрипта

3.2. если нет - прерывай скрипт.

4. после отработки скрипта удаляй или очищай файл.

Таким образом 2й запущенный скрипт прервёт (или как ты там запрограммируешь) 1й запущенный.

По аналогии можно сделать, чтобы прерывались все "новые" скрипты, пока не завершится текущий (но стоит предусмотреть сброс флага, если скрипт отработает с ошибкой, например добавить метку времени начала его работы - и если она старше, например, 3х часов - принудительно убирать флаг)

Но я бы дважды подумал, прежде чем отказываться от крона. Если скрипт "не часто используемый", надёжнее запускать его по расписанию.